# Extract substrings with matcher and regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this string format in Java:

```
Roma Termini 15:00 Milano Centrale 17:55 02:55 FRECCIAROSSA 9638 Price starting from 86.00 ? Select
```

results must be:

```
    Roma Termini
    15:00
    Milano Centrale
    17:55
    02.55
    FRECCIAROSSA
    9638
    86.00
```

SubString like 'Roma Termini' can contain parenthesis. Eg. 'Roma (tutte le stazioni)'

I tried various solution with `Matcher`, but result is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I'm newbie in regex, i tried this:

    ([A-Za-z\(\)\s]+) (\d{2}:\d{2}) ([A-Za-z\(\)\s]+) (\d{2}:\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}) ([A-Za-z\(\)\s]+) (\d+) [a-zA-Z\s]+ (\d{2}\. \d{2})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[A-Z]\w+\s([A-Z]\w+|[\(].*[\)])+|([0-9:]+(?:(\.[\s]|\.)[0-9]*)?)
```

Use the above like this:

```
String s="Roma Termini 15:00 Milano Centrale 17:55 02:55 FRECCIAROSSA 9638 Price starting from 86.00 ? Select";
       Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]\\w+\\s([A-Z]\\w+|[\\(].*[\\)])+|([0-9:]+(?:(\\.[\\s]|\\.)[0-9]*)?)");
       Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/blR9Q5)

Comment: don't work! I inserted your regex in:
`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]\\w+\\s([A-Z]\\w+|[\\(].*[\\)])+|[0-9:]+(?:\\.[0-9]*)?");`

Comment: I don't know about Java but i think there will be method called `Matches`. Have you tried that ?

Comment: I know `Matcher.matches()` (that return false!), the code was written for errors check.

Comment: i tried `string.split("YOUR Regex");` but result is:
array[1 space, 2 spaces, 2 spaces, 2 spaces, 2 spaces, 2 spaces, FRECCIAROSSA, Price starting from, 1space, ? Select=]
Where space are whitespace

Comment: @d3vnico now check it out. It works. Mark it as answer and upvote if it helps plz.. :)

Comment: but you asked for matching 86.00

Comment: `86 .00` is in the string, but, if possible, result must be `86.00`. But I can accept `86 .00` too and delete whitespace in second time.

Comment: Mate you should have said that before

Comment: @d3vnico I've edited my answer. Can I ask +1 for that ?

Comment: I can't, my reputation is low.

Answer (score 1):

For your example input String, you want to exclude "less important" stuff like `"Price starting from"` from your output. It seems you want to traverse over the data like origin/destination/time (*relatively important data*).

You should ask yourself, **where does your input string come from?** From a database after a set of queries? After parsing an XML file? Answer it and then use the same resource to build your desired output. This is the reasonable way, don't waste your time with parsing your input string.

Comment: I must use regex for my project. I can't modify the method that constract the string.

Comment: @d3vnico you will not modify the method that constructs your string, you will reuse it with some modifications under the name of a new method.

Comment: I must use regex. In a better world maybe I could follow your line of reasoning but i can't...